# How do I configure settings for my Python Flask app on GoDaddy

Tags: python, heroku, dns, hosting, custom-domain

This app is working fine on heroku but how do i configure it on godaddy using custom domain.
When i navigate to custom domain, it redirects to mcc.godaddy.com.
What all settings need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a correct CNAME record and wait till the value you entered has propagated.

Go to DNS management and make following changes:

In the 'Host' field enter 'www' and in 'Points to' field add 'yourappname.herokuapp.com'